# Python find words with first letter capitalized followed by alphanumeric characters in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Input: `"We are Testing."`

Output: `['We', 'Testing']`

Input: `"Hello1 Hello2 Hello3"`

Output: `['Hello1', 'Hello2', 'Hello3']`

if there are no such words in the string then return 'None'

Is there an efficient way to go about this, I tried splitting up the string but doesn't seem to be working very well.

Comment: So to clarify, you want to keep only "words" that start with a capital letter, and split the string into a list of those words?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified. Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Use List comprehension along with str.split(), str.isalnum() and str.isupper(). https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with a list comprehension.

```
def find(string):
...     s = [s for s in string.split(" ") if s[0].isupper()]
...     return s or None
...
>>> print(find("no one is here"))
None
>>> print(find("Hello world"))
['Hello']
>>> print(find("We are Testing."))
['We', 'Testing.']
>>> print(find("Hello1 Hello2 Hello3"))
['Hello1', 'Hello2', 'Hello3']
```

Answer (score 1):

Function takes string as a parameter and processes it

```
def finder(string):
    words_list = string.split(' ')

    # Check if the first letter is uppercase and is alphanumerical
    # Else remove the word from list
    words_list = [i for i in words_list if i == i.capitalize() and i.isalnum()]

    return words_list
```